# How can I use MySQL from parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to make use of existing **MySQL** database from **Parse**.
I google thoroughly but could not find relevant search results.
I know **Parse** uses **NoSQL** techniques to store objects and MySQL is relational database. So please guide me on how to accomplish that ?

**EDIT**

I want to be able to pull the existing information and use it in the app from the existing database.

Use case:

I have blood donation website build on **Php and MySQL** and now I want to develop mobile app for users. So it is much like extension to website. So obviously we will be using existing database.

Comment: Can you add more details describe what you want? For example, add some example cases. What do you want to do with MySQL and Parse.com together? And by the way, Parse is relational, not NoQSL.

Comment: @piojo, doesn't Parse use Mongo? Did they change that to a relational database?

Comment: @piojo Please see the post again I have updated my question with use case.

Comment: @mahendrakawde I didn't mean what they use as a backend--I mean they provide a relational API. So I guess it's a NoSQL database with a somewhat relational API.

Comment: Also, I saw your edit, and I would suggest you use the same database for that. Replicating a database (unless you are an expert and you know exactly what you are doing) is asking for errors like data inconsisteny. Just use MySQL in the mobile app.

Comment: @piojo so Parse uses NoSQL(mongoDB) OR relational ?

Comment: @mahendrakawde Parse.com is a relational database. This is because its API lets us organize and query our data based on the relationship between rows (parse objects). But it stores its data internally as NoSQL.

Comment: @piojo I have other thread where someone has answered me on that. But it is little confusing me. Can you help me out to make me understand answer given there ?
Here is the thread link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583013/connect-parse-with-external-database/31589805#31589805

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84138/discussion-between-mahendra-kawde-and-piojo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse uses MongoDB under the hood, and wraps that for you. This means you can only access that database via Parse's Mongo wrapper. MySQL is not in the picture - there is no relational database being operated.

If you're operating your own MySQL server elsewhere and want to use that, you'll need to handle that yourself. You could do this from the client or server, using whatever MySQL solutions are available to that environment.

For instance, you should be able to make a Parse cloud function and use a Node.js module in it to fetch or write data to your separate MySQL database.

Kind of weird though?

EDIT: As per your edit:

I'd recommend you follow my cloud function example from above. A good way to try and tackle this would be:

1. Use plain Node.js (not connected to your mobile app or anything) to simply exercise pulling data from your existing MySQL server.
2. Create a cloud function and try to move your Node.js implementation there.
3. Make your mobile app use that cloud function.

Comment: @mahendrakawde, I've updated my answer with some quick advice.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this thread and help me in understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583013/connect-parse-with-external-database/31589805#31589805

Comment: Can you please have a look at this thread and help me in understanding answer given there ? Link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583013/connect-parse-with-external-database/31589805#31589805

Comment: @mahendrakawde, his advice is similar to mine - use Parse cloud functions to communicate with your MySQL server and get your mobile app to use those cloud functions. Step 1 of my recommendation is to first use plain Node.js and establish communication with your MySQL server. I recommended this because cloud functions are written with and use Node.js, so you can exercise with that before bringing Parse (and more complication) into the mix.